# Best practices for efficiently storing md5 hashes in mysql

Tags: mysql, passwords, md5

Possible field types:

```
BINARY(16)
CHAR(32)
BIGINT + BIGINT
```

How do I decide which one to use?

Comment: An MD5 hash is typically expressed as a 32 digit hex number. CHAR(32) will work just fine.

Comment: None. Don't use MD5, it's a [dead hash](http://valerieaurora.org/hash.html). Use SHA-2 or above, and store is as a series of hex characters (64 characters). It's very nice to read, in this fashion, and it's the standard approach.

Comment: im no good at MySql but a hash is nomaly a byte array so BINARY(16) should be the best, but it might be harder to write custom sql questions against Binary if thats needed?

Comment: @NoonSilk
MD5 is a perfectly acceptable has for non cryptographic reasons(e.g. duplicate detection), but should not be used for passwords due to rainbow tables.

Comment: @NoonSilk it depends totally on what the hash is used for. Storing a MD5 in two 64bit integers is the way to go

Answer (score 45, accepted):

If the column is indexed and you know what you're doing, `BINARY(16)` for performance reasons.

Otherwise, `CHAR(32)` is fine. Make sure the column uses the ascii charset though. (`ascii_bin` for example)

Comment: UNHEX() will convert an MD5 into a binary string.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_unhex

Comment: And then use HEX() when SELECTing to convert back from binary into the more readable hexadecimal form.

Answer (score 0):

Is it not clear if you mean efficient storage or performance wise.
Btw. don't use it to store passwords.

But I used this for a project.

#### Two generated `BIGINT` columns

Add these two columns to your table.

```sql
`md5_l` bigint(20) UNSIGNED GENERATED ALWAYS AS (conv(left(md5(`text`),16),16,10)) STORED,
`md5_r` bigint(20) UNSIGNED GENERATED ALWAYS AS (conv(right(md5(`text`),16),16,10)) STORED,
```

It might or might not help to create a PK on these two columns though, as it probably concatenates two string representations and hashes the result. It would kind of defeat your purpose and a full scan might be quicker but that depends on the situation and specifically on the number of columns and records.

#### Select

Don't try to read these bigints in languages such as php as it doesn't have unsigned integers (and might convert to float), just stay in sql realm and do something like:

```sql
select email into result from `address`
    where url_md5_l=conv(left(md5(the_email),16),16,10)
      and url_md5_r=conv(right(md5(the_email),16),16,10) limit 1;
```

MD5 does collide and is not longer a save way of storing passwords. For other less critical data it is ok.